# Mockito and Deffered Result

Tags: java, powermock, spring-test, powermockito

I have a spring based project and I am trying to improve the code coverage within it

I have the following block of code which uses a lambda on the defferedResult onCompletion method

```
        util.getResponse(userInfoDeferredResult, url, userName, password);

    userInfoDeferredResult.onCompletion(() -> {
        //the result can be a String or ErrorResponse
        //if ErrorResponse we don't want to cause ClassCastException and we don't need to cache the result
        if (userInfoDeferredResult.getResult() instanceof String){

            String response = (String) userInfoDeferredResult.getResult();

            cacheServices.addValueToCache(Service.USER_INFO_CACHE_NAME, corpId, response);              
        }
    });
```

I was wondering - is it possible to mock the contents of the onCompletion lambda using mockito or powerMockito?

Comment: What part of this you want to test? The lambda is already in your code - it is impossible to mock just a lambda.

Comment: I would like to test the inside of the lambda but it seems that is not possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extract contents to new method:

```
if(userInfoDeferredResult.getResult() instanceof String) {
     String response = (String) userInfoDeferredResult.getResult();
     cacheServices.addValueToCache(Service.USER_INFO_CACHE_NAME, corpId, response);              
 }
```

Then test the method that way?

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to not have to do that. I would like to get a solution that is lambda friendly but this is a good approach if there are no alternatives

Answer (score 4):

Your test should rather mock cacheServices, and execute the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting contents to new method is good solution in this case as mentioned in other answer.

Also, you can find article about in the following link:
http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/12/unit-testing-java-8-lambda-expressions-and-streams.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally I prefer not to change the service code for test code (for example extracting to method and make it public although it should be private). The `onCompletion` method is triggered when the `completed` of `AsyncContext` is called. So you can test in the following way:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DeferredResultController.class)
public class DeferredResultControllerUnitTest {

    @MockBean
    CacheServices cacheServices;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void onCompletionTest() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/your_url"))
                .andDo(mvcResult -> mvcResult.getRequest().getAsyncContext().complete());
        Mockito.verify(cacheServices)
               .addValueToCache(Service.USER_INFO_CACHE_NAME, getExpextedCorpId(), getExpectedResponse());
        }
    }
```

Working [github example here](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/springAsyncServlet/DeferredResultControllerUnitTest.java).

In contrast to [`@SpringBootTest`](https://github.com/elirandav/springAsyncServlet/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/springAsyncServlet/DeferredResultControllerWebTest.java), `@WebMvcTest` won't start the all Spring application context so it is more lighter.